# How to move some keys to another key of object via lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I started to learn lodash and can't understand how to move keys to another key of same object. From API i get next data (users list):

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "test1",
    "phone": null,
    "email": "test1@gmail.com",
    "role": "admin",
    "language": "en",
    "created_at": "2016-12-16 14:25:23",
    "updated_at": "2016-12-16 14:25:23"
}, ... ]
```

And i want to get

```
[
{
    "hidden": {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "test1",
            "language": "en",
            "created_at": "2016-12-16 14:25:23",
            "updated_at": "2016-12-16 14:25:23"
    },
    "phone": null,
    "email": "test1@gmail.com",
    "role": "admin"
},
{
    "hidden": {
            "id": 2,
            "username": "test2",
            "language": "en",
            "created_at": "2017-09-22 10:45:00",
            "updated_at": "2017-09-22 10:45:00"
    },
    "phone": null,
    "email": "test2@gmail.com",
    "role": "moderator"
}
```

]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With lodash, you can [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) the array, and use [`_.pick()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick),  [`_.omit()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omit), and [`_.assign()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#assign) to shape the new object:

```js
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "test1",
    "phone": null,
    "email": "test1@gmail.com",
    "role": "admin",
    "language": "en",
    "created_at": "2016-12-16 14:25:23",
    "updated_at": "2016-12-16 14:25:23"
}];

var baseKeys = ['phone', 'email', 'role'];

var result = _.map(data, function(o) {
  return _.assign(_.pick(o, baseKeys), {
    hidden: _.omit(o, baseKeys)
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Another option is ES6 with [Rest/Spread Properties](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) (requires babel with [Object rest spread transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/)). [Map](https://mdn-mixmix.hashbase.io/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map.html) the array, and then extract the properties using destructuring and object rest. Assemble the new object using [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015):

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "test1",
    "phone": null,
    "email": "test1@gmail.com",
    "role": "admin",
    "language": "en",
    "created_at": "2016-12-16 14:25:23",
    "updated_at": "2016-12-16 14:25:23"
}];

const result = data.map(({ phone, email, role, ...hidden }) => ({
  phone, 
  email, 
  role,
  hidden
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: welcome :) Indeed ES6 tends to create clean code. However, note that object rest/spread is not ES6, but a proposal, and you'll need babel with the transform plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You could destruct the object and reassemble the object.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, username: "test1", phone: null, email: "test1@gmail.com", role: "admin", language: "en", created_at: "2016-12-16 14:25:23", updated_at: "2016-12-16 14:25:23" }],
    result = data.map(({ id, username, phone, email, role, language, created_at, updated_at }) => ({
        phone,
        email,
        role,
        hidden: { id, username, language, created_at, updated_at }
    }));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const newArray = _.map(array,(obj) => {
  return {
    hidden: _.pick(obj, ['id', 'username', 'language', 'created_at', 'updated_at']),
    phone: obj.phone,
    email: obj.email,
    role: obj.role
  }
}
```

You cannot move them but you can [_.pick()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick) them.